# Partition Spark DataFrame by column value and write paritioned data into MULTIPLE S3 buckets in parallel

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Let's say I have Spark dataframe in the following shape:

```
Customers(id: Long, fname: String, lname: String)

[1, Fname1, Lname1]
[2, Fname2, Lname2]
[3, Fname3, Lname3]
[4, Fname4, Lname4]
```

I want to partition the data frame based on the id and upload partitioned dataframe into AWS S3 buckets whose name include id such as `example-customer-bucket-{id}`.  As a result, the `[1, Fname1, Lname1]` is uploaded into bucket `example-customer-bucket-1` and so on.

Is there a Scala/Spark function can handle partition and write altogether? Or do I have to iterate data over loop?

Comment: Putting different customers in separate buckets in S3 sounds like an architectural disaster; I really don't think this is what you actually want to do? Can you elaborate more on why you are trying to do this?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. We need to share customer data with each customer and each customer owns a S3 bucket with `id` being part of bucket name. We don't want to share data about customer A with customer B, hence I need to partition the frame based on the id.

Comment: OK; is your real world problem sharing a single row of customer data or many rows (e.g. From transactional data)?

Comment: The dataFrame can include multiple rows with the same id. In that case, we will share all rows have the same id in one file with the customer of that id.

Comment: OK, what I would do is partition the data on customer Id on output to a single bucket. The syntax is something like dataframe.write.partitionBy("id").parquet("full path"). Then separately write a script (not in Scala) that copies the appropriate  partition by path into each customers private bucket.